# Linear Operators Injectivity and Surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose T $\in L(P(R))$ is such that T is injective and deg Tp $\leq$ deg p for every nonzero polynomial p $\in P(R)$. Prove that T is surjective and that deg Tp = deg p for every nonzero p $\in P(R)$.

Really stumped on this one can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Restrict $T$ to the finite-dimensional subspace of polynomials with degree $\leq d$. This restriction is a bijection, since $T$ is injective. Suppose some polynomial of degree $d$ is mapped to a polynomial of degree $<d$, then $T$ cannot be surjective, since there is a polynomial of degree $<d$ also mapped to that polynomial. So $T$ maps polynomials of degree $d$ to polynomials of degree $d$ and is surjective.